# I want to add some detection to my website; are these good choices?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, css

As I am recoding my entire website, I need to choose a couple of methods to detect both web browsers and mobile devices. From the lists below, could you please recommend the better option?

Here are my choices;

**Browser Detection**

- Use IE-specific comment arguments to target IE6 - IE8 CSS files; IE9+ and other browsers will use the same CSS file
- Web browser user agent string matches via PHP (not *entire* user agent strings!)

**Mobile Device Detection**

- CSS3 media queries, although this could be problematic for IE versions that don't support them, and also for detecting mobile devices with resolutions capable of displaying the full website (such as a 4.7" 1080p display, or a 7" 1080p display)
- User agent string matches via PHP (again, not *entire* strings!)

Ideally, I'd like all mobile devices (smartphones and tablets) to display the mobile version of the website, and be given the option to view the desktop version via a user agent switch, which I know Chrome, Firefox and Opera on Android offer (at the very least).

Thank you.

Comment: You may find tools such as http://html5boilerplate.com/ useful (in short: conditional comments and css media queries). If you avoid user agent sniffing (and you should) you'll avoid problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use browser detection, but **feature** detection. For this, I highly recommend [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

In regards to device detection, I use [PHP Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/tags), it works fantastically. However, most of the time you can get away with merely doing screensize detection via media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width:759px){
    /* mobile CSS */
}

@media screen and (min-width:760px){
    /* browser CSS */
}
```

That is obviously oversimplified, you can set it to whatever sizes you want, and have multiple versions (tablet, giant screen, etc.). [More information can be found here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

That said, media queries are not supported with IE8 and below, so you need to do a Javascript-based detection. If you use Modernizr, you can just detect it, replicate the screen-size CSS in a separate file, and apply that CSS file dynamically by giving your CSS link an ID:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" id="ApplyQueries" href="queries.css" />
```

And then dynamically apply the right file by screensize:

```
if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 760){
    document.getElementById('ApplyQueries').href = 'mobile.css';
} else {
    document.getElementById('ApplyQueries').href = 'browser.css';
}
```

Again this is over-simplified, but should give you an idea of where to start.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using plugins like Modernizr, Initializr and HTML5shiv, thus removing the requirement for JavaScript, but if that's only necessary for IE8 and below ... well, I guess that will have to do.

Comment: As much as a proponent of "as little Javascript as possible", inevitably if you want to provide the richest client experience possible feature detection is necessary, and can only be done on Javascript. I personally don't often use Modernizr, however there are some necessary feature detection pieces (CSS animations, media queries, audio/video format support) that can only be tested with Javascript.

Comment: After rethinking the situation, I feel that this is the best way to go. Media queries will only be used to detect mobile devices and printers, while IE conditional comments will be used to provide a specific CSS file to each version of IE, and as IE8 isn't used on Windows Phone, and is instead only used on a desktop machine (which usually have resolutions of 1024-wide minimum), I don't think media queries will matter too much there in any case. My website will require a resolution width of 1024 pixels to display the full 'desktop' version; the mobile version will be displayed otherwise.